# iron-router loading template forever

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router

My problem is I have to create post but once I thought to take me to the page that shows me the post I created my url so

midomain.com / post / id

meteor and use iron-router but when I post the remains loading forever and never shows me the page

midomain.com / post / id

I'm doing the subscriptions and publications also manually...

Configuration iron-router

```
    Router.map(function(){
      this.route('showSnippet', {
        path:'/snippets/:_id',
        controller:'SnippetShowController',
        action:'show'
      });
      this.route('home', {
        path:'/',
        template:'form'
      })
    });
    SnippetShowController = RouteController.extend({

      before: function () {
        var _id = this.params._id;

        if(App.subs.snippet)
          App.subs.snippet.stop();

        App.subs.snippet = Meteor.subscribe('snippet', _id);
      },
      data: function () {
        return Snippets.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
      },

      run: function () {
        this.render('showSnippet');
      }
    });
```

subscriptions

```
    App = {
        subs: {
            snippets: Meteor.subscribe('snippets')
        }
    };
```

publications

```
    Meteor.publish('snippet', function (id) {
        return Snippets.find({_id: id});
    });
```

I want to clarify that 'posts' I mean my collection called 'snippets' 
after performing validation when clicking on the 'submit' form I have

```
Router.go ('showSnippet');`
```

Thanks!

Sorry for my English but I use Google translator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
before: function () {
  var _id = this.params._id;
  if(App.subs.snippet)
    App.subs.snippet.stop();
  App.subs.snippet = Meteor.subscribe('snippet', _id);
}
```

with

```
before: function () {
  var _id = this.params._id;
  this.subscribe('snippet', _id).wait();
}
```

or

```
waitOn: function () {
  var _id = this.params._id;
  return Meteor.subscribe('snippet', _id);
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks, 
unfortunately this does not work, and now I get the console 
You Route.prototype.resolve called with a missing parameter. "_id" not found in params
any idea why this happens? 
in my collection called 'snippets' I have 
languaje name and _id 
this warning should not go

Comment: Because `this.render('showSnippet');` or `Router.go('showSnippet');` require a data context. showSnippet path requires and _id param therefore you must call `this.render('showSnippet', {_id: XXXXXX});` or some document that has an _id property. So to sum up, first you need to fix your code like the example in my answer, then you need to call the routes by passing in a data context.

Comment: mmm you could help me? I really do not like taking the id of the 'snippet' reciend created

Comment: Since your route requires an ID parameter, you cannot just call it by only the route name. You must include either an ID, a javascript with an _id key, or a data context that comes from a collection's document. If you need to know more, you need to ask a more detailed question with more code that shows exactly where and how you are using the routes.

Comment: Serkan, really thank you very much ... you could give me a link or something doumentación as videos or somewhere to explain this kind of thing that is like driving routes with iron-router and pass parameters and that, I hope not too much to ask .

Comment: Sure, you can take a look at https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router and https://www.eventedmind.com/tracks/feed-archive/meteor-ironrouter And if you find my answer useful and solving your question, you can mark it as accepted by clicking on the checkmark.